# Rails & Cells: render array inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trailblazer

Right now array inside cells render like a string. How I can render an array like array inside cell view?

```
def skill_options
  ["js", "ruby"]
end
```

call:

```
<%= skill_options %>
```

render:

```
array outside cell: ["js", "ruby"]

array inside cell: jsruby
```

Comment: It looks like you *are* rendering the array.

Comment: Inside cells it render like a string

Comment: What do you mean, "render like array"?

Comment: I want get behavior like in usual erb: ‘["js", "ruby"]’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call:

```
<%= raw(skill_options) %>
```

render array inside cell:

```
array inside cell: ["js", "ruby"]
```